# How should I code this `@ViewBuilder` function for conditional contextMenu?

Tags: swiftui, conditional-statements, contextmenu, function-builder

Because the code for compositing context menu is a little lengthy, I want to code it like this:

```
var body: some View {
    Text("Hello World")
            .contextMenu(changingStatusID == nil ? contextMenu() : nil)
}

@ViewBuilder
func contextMenu() -> ContextMenu { //<-- Problem goes here, I don't know how to set the parameters and it's return type
    ContextMenu {
        Button {
            edit()
        } label: {
            Label("Edit", systemImage: "rectangle.and.pencil.and.ellipsis")
        }
        Divider()
        if #available(macOS 12.0, *) {
            Button(role: .destructive) {
                do {
                    try delete()
                }
                catch {
                    showAlert = true
                }
            } label: {
                Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
            }
            .alert("Failed to delete.", isPresented: $showAlert) {
                Button("OK", role: .cancel) { }
            }
        } else {
            Button {
                do {
                    try delete()
                }
                catch {
                    showAlert = true
                }
            } label: {
                Label("Delete ⚠︎", systemImage: "trash")
            }
            .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
                Alert(title: Text("Failed"),
                      message: Text("Unable to delete this task."),
                      dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XCode shows error in the line of function name `func contextMenu()`:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'ContextMenu<TupleView<(Button<Label<Text, Image>>, Divider, _ConditionalContent<AnyView, some View>)>>' to specified type '<<error type>>'

Reference to generic type 'ContextMenu' requires arguments in <...> Insert '<<#MenuItems: View#>>'

Static method 'buildBlock' requires that 'ContextMenu<TupleView<(Button<Label<Text, Image>>, Divider, _ConditionalContent<AnyView, some View>)>>' conform to 'View'
```

Comment: Try replacing the return type `ContextMenu` with `some View`. The compile should infer the concrete type

Comment: Tried, not working. `Return type of instance method 'contextMenu()' requires that 'ContextMenu<TupleView<(Button<Label<Text, Image>>, Divider, _ConditionalContent<AnyView, some View>)>>' conform to 'View'`

Comment: @ChrisR just remind me that the key is to use .contextMenu{ if showContext {myContextMenu()}} instead of using .contextMenu(shouldShowMenu ? myContextMenu() : nil), now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach that works:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var showContext = true
    @State private var showAlert = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle("show contextMenu", isOn: $showContext)
            
            Text("Hello World")
                .contextMenu {
                    if showContext {
                        myContextMenu()
                    }
                }
        }
        .padding()
    }

    
    @ViewBuilder
    func myContextMenu() -> some View {
//        ContextMenu { // not needed
            Button {
                //edit()
            } label: {
                Label("Edit", systemImage: "rectangle.and.pencil.and.ellipsis")
            }
            Divider()
            Button(role: .destructive) {
                do {
                    //try delete()
                }
                catch {
                    showAlert = true
                }
            } label: {
                Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
            }
            .alert("Failed to delete.", isPresented: $showAlert) {
                Button("OK", role: .cancel) { }
            }
//        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you just remind me the key is to use `.contextMenu{ if showContext {myContextMenu()}}` instead of using `.contextMenu(shouldShowMenu ? myContextMenu() : nil)`, now it works like a charm.